# I am trying to upload images via multer in nodejs but from client when i send data i am getting error?

Tags: reactjs, node.js, multer

I am trying to upload image via multer but i am getting this error in my backend.

> Error: User validation failed: picturePath: Cast to string failed for value "{}" (type Object) at path "picturePath"

please help me as i am learning mern stack devlopment.

register.jsx

/* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";
import { BASE_URL } from "../constants/constants";

    const Register = () => {
      const [name, setName] = useState("");
      const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
      const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
      const [picturePath, setPicturePath] = useState("");
      const [fileName, setFileName] = useState("");
    
      const navigate = useNavigate();
    
      const handlePicturePathChange = (event) => {
        const file = event.target.files[0];
        const reader = new FileReader();
        console.log(reader);
        reader.onloadend = () => {
          setPicturePath(reader.result);
          setFileName(file.name);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      };
    
      const handleSubmit = async () => {
        const formData = new FormData();
    
        formData.append("name", name);
        formData.append("email", email);
        formData.append("password", password);
        if (picturePath) {
          formData.append("picturePath", picturePath);
        }
        try {
          const config = {
            headers: {
              "Content-type": "application/json",
            },
          };
    
          const result = await axios.post(
            `${BASE_URL}api/auth/register`,
            formData,
            config
          );
    
          console.log(result);
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
        }
      };
      return (
        <div className="auth-container">
          <div className="auth-form">
            <header>Sign Up</header>
            <div className="input">
              <label>Full name</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                name="name"
                placeholder="Enter Your Name"
                value={name}
                onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
                required
              />
            </div>
            <div className="input">
              <label>Email</label>
              <input
                type="email"
                name="email"
                placeholder="Enter Your Email"
                value={email}
                onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                required
              />
            </div>
            <div className="input">
              <label>Password</label>
              <input
                type="password"
                name="password"
                placeholder="Enter Strong Password"
                value={password}
                onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                required
              />
            </div>
            <div className="input">
              <input
                type="file"
                name="picturePath"
                onChange={handlePicturePathChange}
                required
              />
            </div>
            <div className="auth-form-btn">
              <button className="auth-btn" onClick={handleSubmit}>
                Sign Up
              </button>
            </div>
            <div className="login">
              Already have an account? <Link to="/login">Sign In</Link>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    export default Register;
```

user.js

```
const registerUser = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { name, email, password, picturePath } = req.body;

    console.log(req.body);

    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);

    const existingUser = await User.findOne({ email });

    if (existingUser) {
      return res
        .status(401)
        .send("User Already Exist please enter unique email address");
    }

    const newUser = await User.create({
      name: name,
      email: email,
      password: hashedPassword,
      picturePath: picturePath,
    });
    console.log("New user:", newUser);

    res.status(200).send({
      name: newUser.name,
      email: newUser.email,
      token: generateToken(newUser._id),
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

userModel.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    picturePath: {
      type: String,
      default: "",
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

Your help will be lindly appreciated..

Comment: It seems you might need to change headers to multipart 
`headers: {
            "Contetnt-Type":"multipart/form-data" 
 }`. Make sure your file is uploaded or added successfully before you submit the form.

Comment: but i am using independent input not form as a learner can you give me some insight why i use this